# What is the real purpose of application.ini

Tags: php, zend-framework, config

I am a Zend developer. I just want to know the real purpose of the application.ini file. As far as I understood, it is used to specify the locations of controllers, views, models, modules, session and library files (Acl & VanityUrl) and to Connect to database. Anything else about it? Please help me if you have something else.

Cheers...!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a Configuration file,

1. Every configuration to the project is defined in this file in a
   specific format.
2. It handle error display, bootstrap file handling.
3. All the controller files handling and all the above mentioned in
   your question itself.
4. You can also define the configuration as per server i.e. production
   server, development/testing, staging server etc....
5. All the permission hanlding to any specific functionality is done
   here.
6. Newly installed Plugins in framewirk needs to be registered here in
   application.ini file.
7. Routing is also configured herein application.ini file

I hope above are few of the "something else" points you were looking for... Cheers!!! :)

Comment: +1, also you can specify options for your libraries using resources

Comment: @Dubious if the answer is helpful then do not forget to check mark the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, you can use it to configure many aspects of your application through one of the [Resource Plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html).  In addition, you can configure `php.ini` options, configure [Routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html), and set options for your own application.

It is also possible to have an empty `application.ini` and configure everything in the Bootstrap, but the `application.ini` file is much easier to read and make changes to than it would be to do all of that in the bootstrap.  And with the help of the resource plugins, it is often much easier to configure them in the `ini` file instead of in code.